# ajax angular local loading browser issue

Tags: ajax, angularjs, google-chrome

I got these includes to work with angular offline but because of the ajax it only works in firefox. Is there a way to get this to work in any browser locally with no internet. This is a demo that non computer savvy people will have to use.

```
<!-- Test -->
<div ng-include src="'_includes/link.html'"></div>
```

So the users will not know how to go to command prompt etc.

Comment: you should try with data-ng-include

Answer (score 0):

normally I use like:

```
      <div data-ng-include="'_includes/link.html'"></div>
```

[reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude)

Answer (score 0):

You can cache your service data into the local storage and if not connected then use from there.

See for [more detail](https://quickleft.com/blog/making-your-app-work-offline-tips-and-cautionary-tales/)

Answer (score 0):

I use this code:

```
<div ng-include="'views/example.html'"></div>
```